# Converting epoch to UTC date format using date.h

Tags: c++

A very simple question. I have been using date.h to get epoch in milliseconds and nanoseconds from a full datestamp.

```
     istringstream temp_ss1{timestamp1};
     sys_time<nanoseconds> tp1;
     temp_ss1 >> parse("%Y/%m/%d,%T", tp1);
     std::cout << tp1.time_since_epoch().count() << "ns\n";
```

What is the method to go from a millisecond epoch to a full datestamp with milliseconds?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not picky about the format, you can stream the `sys_time<milliseconds>` out.  If you would like to control the format, you can use `date::format` with [these formatting flags](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#to_stream_formatting).  For example:

```
std::cout << format("%Y/%m/%d,%T", tp1) << '\n';
```

The precision of the output will match the precision of the `time_point`.

> Is there a method to convert. "long epoch = 1609330278454" is there a function which take a long and prints a date?

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    long epoch = 1609330278454;
    cout << sys_time<milliseconds>{milliseconds{epoch}} << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
2020-12-30 12:11:18.454
```

You can customize the format like so:

```
long epoch = 1609330278454;
sys_time<milliseconds> tp{milliseconds{epoch}};
cout << format("%Y/%m/%d,%T", tp) << '\n';
```

Output:

```
2020/12/30,12:11:18.454
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. Is there a method to convert. "long epoch = 1609330278454" is there a function which take a long and prints a date ?

Comment: Updated answer with example code to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.